# Some questions about iterator and n log n solution

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

My code is described as below:

My problem: Given a number and another sequence of other number, find the index of the closest value that is greater or equal to the number.
First: I don't know what datastructures suitable for this.

Second: My solution cost O(n^2) time complexity because I think I use distance function which cost O(n) time . But I don't know any other solutions O(nlogn)

```
Multiset  St;
for (int i = 0; i < array.size();i++)
{ 
St.insert(arr[i]) // insert number from an array
multiset <long long> :: iterator it; 
it = lower_bound(value) // find the index of the closest element larger than the value. 
int dis = distance (st.begin(), it); 
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of your problem. And if this is C++, write code, not something which resambles code.

Comment: It's very difficult to suggest anything without knowing what the problem you're solving is.

Comment: what does `loop ->` mean?

Comment: Okay sorry so much, I will adapt it immediately

Comment: Your solution is basically correct except that you need to check out the return value of lower_bould. Another similar way may faster:  just sort the array, and call the generall version :https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

Comment: Thank you and I have checked it in my code, but my solution still cost O(n^2) time

Comment: "Given a number find the index of the value that is greater or equal to the number." Surely that should be "Given a number and a sequence of other numbers, find the index in that sequence of the value that is greater or equal to the number" Putting things into a multiset doesn't help knowing where in the original sequence they were, unless that sequence is sorted.

Comment: Okay thanks for your feedback, I have refined it :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but it looks like an O(n) problem to me:

```
int best = INT_MAX;
int ibest = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) { 
     if (val <= arr[i] && arr[i] < best) {
        best = arr[i];
        ibest = i;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Unless the OP has left out some condition O(N) must be the best and optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a basic binary search for this, store the numbers in sorted order in a vector of pairs. The first value of pair will be the value and the second value will be the index of that number in `arr`. Binary search for `value` which will do the task in `O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

But I think inserting in an sorted array will cost O(n) time

Comment: You don't need to insert in a sorted array. Step 1: build the array of pairs (value, index). Step 2: sort the array of pairs; Step 3: binary search on the sorted array of pairs. Cost: Step 1 is O(n), Step 2 is O(n log(n)), Step 3 is O(log(n)). Total cost: O(n log(n)).